# Magento 2 How to cancel the order during the process

Tags: magento2, sales-order, sales

I would like to know if there is a way to cancel the order during the creation process, I have a model that calls an api, if this API result is false, I would like to cancel the order even before it is created, the same happens when payment is declined

is it possible to do that?

Comment: Yes you can do this overriding cancel controller or you may need to create plugin, It is possible.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks so much. just for the record, i didn't want the code, i was just to know if it was even possible, thank you sir.